# Unable to properly disable the alerts within the web application level in SharePoint 2013 server using power shell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, alert

I have a requirement to move 500 SharePoint web applications to new server.So before moving the application want to disable the alerts at web application level so that no alert notifications gets triggered immediately after the movement. Then want to enable the alerts in new server.

I tried below PowerShell to verify that on one web application in current environment and power shell got executed successfully and also if I check in general settings of the web applications alert is off.

```
$weburl= Get-SPWebApplication "http://Webapplication1/"
$weburl.AlertsEnabled = $false
$weburl.Update()
```

Still then I am getting alerts if some one creates new item in list or Library as I had subscribed prior to alert me on those list/libraries.

*Please guide me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Well your code seems perfectly fine. Do you use only out of the box alerts or maybe you have some 3rd party feature for the alerts?. Have you tried disabling it explicitly for a list? http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/07/disable-alerts-on-sharepoint-2013-list-using-powershell.html

Comment: another approach could be to disable the timer job that sends those alerts. this timer job is called "Immediate Alerts".

Comment: We have only out of box alerts